# Find CCISS version

Tags: linux, hp-proliant, drivers, hp-smart-array

I'm currently running Ubuntu 10.10 and would like to just find out what **version of HP's CCISS RAID array driver** I'm running. I've looked around `hpacucli` and couldn't find anything. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try `modinfo cciss`.

On a CentOS 5.x system, I get:

```
[root@XXX ~]# modinfo cciss 
filename:       /lib/modules/2.6.18-164.15.1.el5/kernel/drivers/block/cciss.ko
license:        GPL
version:        3.6.20-RH4
description:    Driver for HP Controller SA5xxx SA6xxx version 3.6.20-RH4
author:         Hewlett-Packard Company
srcversion:     D7FCFF5E2715B57D70725AC
```

Comment: And a note for the future: HP is moving away from `cciss` as their driver and towards `hpsa`. The same command will work with that.

Comment: Will we see this in RHEL 6 at some point? I haven't really had to deal with the `hpsa` driver yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
hpacucli ctrl all show
```

(this will provide the slot number for your SmartArray controller to be used in the next step)

```
hpacucli ctrl slot=<insert slot number> show detail
```

HP has deprecated hpacucli and replaced it with hpsacli, the syntax is the same